# HTC 7 thropy white screen

Tags: 7.5, 7.8, soft-reset

I have a problem with my wp7 phone. It crashes very often with a white screen.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pxRf.jpg]

It happens randomly, with or without sim card. Sometimes, when it crashes there is a long sound from the speaker (kind of like error) and then it vibrates 5 times and crashes again. I did a reset (settings/about/reset) on it and it crashed two times.

Any ideas?

BTW What I though is settings/about/reset will do a hard reset and restore the software to factory default, but I see that the OS version is 7.10 (was 7.0 when I bought it). But it looks a bit strange. Firstly it doesn't have letters in the app list

[image]

Looks like some 7.5 features are there and aren't.

UPDATE:

My phone is a dev phone and I think it started when I didn't extend my dev account. I'll try to unregister the phone with Developer Phone Registration.

Comment: I encounter exactly the same problem! It looks like it has something to do with memory usage. The problems appeared after I had too much music on my phone... now it still consits (I also tried to change the battery, but it did not help). I do not want to reset the phone as long as there is no way to backup all my data...

Comment: @Aschratt Most likely, but the reset doesn't help. Maybe 7.8 update will help.

Comment: Hope so... still waiting for the rollout.

Comment: btw have you also tried to hard-reset your phone? Also can you tell me if the restart also happens when you are calling someone? For me the restart seems supressed when I am calling somebody (except when I am pushing the call into the background and start another app).

Comment: It crashed while updating to 7.8 ;/

Comment: Have to tried connecting to Zune and rolling back to a previous point in time, if available?

Comment: @karancan yeah. It didn't work. Most likely hardware issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, but after one crash it just showed white screen and nothing more. I did some googling and found out that those devices have an issue with memory card. And i just replaced it with a new one.

On youtube, there are a lot of instructions about disassembling a device: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=htc+trophy+memory+card&oq=htc+trophy+memory+card

Comment: Interesting... I just called HTC Support yesterday and was thinking about sending the phone to get it repaired, but first I will check if I can change the memory card. I let you know if it worked ;)

Comment: Replacing the SD-Card doesn't fix the problem for me, either. I just tried to replace the card with a new one, reset it to factory default, but still the problem persists...